# Reload consumer properties with spring kafka

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-kafka

We have developed live reloading of config properties with spring boot applications. I have a spring-kafka consumer and I wanted to leverage the live reloading where if I change the consumer property I should be able to start the container without rebooting the application. I used:

```
KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.stop()
KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.start()
```

I thought the above actually creates a new container but that is not the case. So I wanted to find out if I have to start a container with new config properties how do I do that

```
 @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "container.config.properties")
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    @RefreshScope
    ContainerConfigProperties containerConfigProperties() {
        return new ContainerConfigProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    @ConditionalOnBean(value = {ContainerConfigProperties.class})
    @RefreshScope
    <K, V> ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<K, ValueDeserializerContainer<V>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(final ConsumerFactory<K, ValueDeserializerContainer<V>> consumerFactory,
                                                                                                                   final ContainerConfigProperties containerConfigProperties,
                                                                                                                   final Optional<IAMIdentity> iamIdentity) {
        val factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<K, ValueDeserializerContainer<V>>();
        factory.setBatchListener(true);
        factory.setBatchErrorHandler(new SeekToCurrentBatchErrorHandler());
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(containerConfigProperties.getAckMode());
        factory.setConcurrency(containerConfigProperties.getConcurrency());
        factory.getContainerProperties().setConsumerRebalanceListener(simpleConsumerRebalanceListener());

        // update kafka consumer properties. Default is taken from the config file
        iamIdentity.ifPresent(identity -> consumerFactory.updateConfigs(addIAMIdentity(identity)));
        log.info("kafkaListenerContainerFactory");

        return factory;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly which properties are you changing? The child containers are indeed recreated when stopping/starting the parent container so any `ContainerProperties` changes will be picked up.

If you are talking about kafka consumer properties, you either need to reconfigure the consumer factory, or set the changed properties via the `ContainerProperties.kafkaConsumerProperties` to override the consumer factory settings.

**EDIT**

Something like this might work:

```java
@Bean
@RefreshScope
Object containerReconfigurer(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.getListenerContainers().forEach(container -> {
        container.stop();
        // reconfigure container
        container.start();
    });
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Updated my post so the consumerFactory gets created by spring kafka coz i have defined all the consumer properties in yaml file. So now lets say if I make changes to the config file and change a consumer property in the yaml file and then call refresh since I have annotated kafkaListenerContainerFactory method with   @RefreshScope I was hoping when the container is started again it will create the bean again. I added the log line as well but that log line is only called once. Do I have to create the bean for consumerFactory in order to get that working?

Comment: No; the containers themselves are not beans, they are stored in the `KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry` bean during initialization and won't be refreshed or recreated. One solution might be to put the listeners in their own child `ApplicationContext` and close it and create a new child context each time the config changes.

Comment: Ok. The last part I did not understand when you say listener you mean the class annotated with @KafkaListener?. If you have an example that would be great coz we really wanted to implement this feature

Comment: I had another idea - see the edit.

Comment: I am not sure how I can reconfigure the container. Ideally we would want to recreate the container coz the properties have changed. There is no method (on the interface) where you can set the new properties.

Comment: Huh? `MessageListenerContainer.getContainerProperties().set...`. If you need to change properties on the container itself, cast it to a `ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer`.

Comment: Oh yeah i can do somehow missed it. thanks for the help