# Not found listeners from KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry

Tags: spring-kafka

I want to update the properties of consumers in runtime.
I found this solution - [Reload consumer properties with spring kafka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72021258/reload-consumer-properties-with-spring-kafka).

But there are no containers at the start of the application. I am using starter from Spring Boot for spring-kafka configuration.

```
@Bean
fun refresh(
    @Qualifier(KafkaListenerConfigUtils.KAFKA_LISTENER_ENDPOINT_REGISTRY_BEAN_NAME)
    registry: KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry
): Any? {
    registry.allListenerContainers.forEach {
        it.stop()

        it.containerProperties.authExceptionRetryInterval
    }

    return null
}
```

What am I doing wrong? And what is the best approach for runtime updating consumers and producers?

Using spring - kafka and starter Spring Boot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic is not correct. You have a `@Bean` and you call that  `registry.allListenerContainers` just on a bean initialization phase. That's the time when there is no created listener containers in a registry yet.

According to the answer you are pointing to you are missing a `@RefreshScope` annotation on this bean definition.

Comment: Is it possible to set such an order so that all containers are registered?

Comment: They are registered in that `KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry` anyway. Your only problem at the moment that you try to stop too early - on bean definition phase, when you probably would like to do that only when `@RefreshScope` does its logic.

Comment: I configure several Consumer Factorybeans without spring boot for several kafka clusters. Will I be able to see in this container all the listeners for all the consumers. How do I understand what their listener id is?

Thanks for the answers, they are useful for me!

Comment: See `@KafkaListener.id()`

Comment: Is it possible to use a different approach? For example `@RefreshScope` using `@KafkaListener`.
And in `@KafkaListener(properties = ...)` using the property key: ${dynamic.properties}.

Comment: No, it's not. The `@KafkaListener` does not expose a bean to which that `@RefreshScope` could be applied automatically.